# Internet connectivity for the Arduino Due using AtmelStudio?

Tags: ethernet, arduino-due, atmel-studio, wifi, tcpip

What hardware and software solutions work and what are the tradeoffs for connecting an Arduino Due to the internet?  I gather the [ethernet hardware](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardEthernet) is much cheaper than [WiFi hardware](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoWiFiShield) (€29 versus €69).  In either case (wired or wireless), what software stacks and drivers work under AtmelStudio?

Comment: Greatt question

Comment: Atmel studio uses c++ right? Porting the Ethernet library cant be that hard.

Comment: Hoping so @TheDoctor.  I see an [Ethernet PHY component](http://asf.atmel.com/docs/3.11.0/sam3x/html/group__dm9161a__ethernet__phy__group.html) and driver in the ASF Wizard but no TCP/IP pieces.  In answer to your question, yes, I see [C++ hints](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19241392/673991) everywhere but I've only used C so far.

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone - That PHY component requires a specific external ethernet PHY (A DM9161A). It will **not** work with the arduino ethernet board/shield, which uses a Wiznet W5100 PHY/coprocessor).

Answer (score 2):

Well, your best bet is to import the arduino libraries in your [Atmel Studio project](http://www.engblaze.com/tutorial-using-atmel-studio-6-with-arduino-projects/). Then you'll be able to use existing code to connect to the "traditional" Ethernet Shield using SPI.

Though, the Sam 3X features an hardware ethernet [that is not wired](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=197083.0), unlike the [MBed LPC1768](http://mbed.org/platforms/mbed-LPC1768/)… Sadly that's the [ethernet PHY component](http://asf.atmel.com/docs/3.11.0/sam3x/html/group__dm9161a__ethernet__phy__group.html) you saw, but won't be able to actually use…

Comment: You could always buy a [Taijiuino Due](http://www.elechouse.com/elechouse/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=72_73&products_id=2224), which is a 3rd party due clone that is code-compatible, but has the ethernet IO lines broken out.

Comment: You mean the [Visual Micro](http://www.visualmicro.com/) plugin for Atmel Studio?  And with that make a TCP/IP server with the EthernetServer class?

Comment: I guess so, though I've not tried that. You may also include the sources or add headers + libraries as dependencies in your project (which is what I do)

Comment: What .c .cpp .h files do you use @zmo?  What kind of TCP/IP features do you have, or are they merely Ethernet?

Comment: This solution means I'd give up ASF (Atmel Studio Framework) correct?

Comment: Er… what are you actually asking? are you asking about the SAM3X Ethernet features, or using an ethernet shield on the Due? Anyway, that does not mean you have to give up ASF, just to complete it with parts of the Arduino framework.

Comment: Your answer says "import the arduino libraries".  Is that possible in a project that includes ASF?  I've only managed to be able to use one or the other, by `New | Project` or `New | Arduino Project`.  If it isn't too noob a question, can you walk me through the exact steps how to import the arduino libraries in a project that uses ASF?